# Inconsistent results in special characters with Apache/PHP/FreeTDS, but not with PHP/FreeTDS from command line

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, freetds

I have two identical servers (called test and production) with Linux Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago), PHP version 5.4.2, Apache Apache 2.4.2, OpenSSL/0.9.8s, freeTDS 0.92-dev (not the best thing but I cannot change that for the moment), and a separate Windows server with Microsoft SQL Server.

I have a PHP script called testfs1.php that reads a string from the database, always the same, and prints the length: nothing else. Of course, the initial situation was much more complex, but I did any effort to simplify.

The database field is NVARCHAR, all the components are set to use UTF-8.

Normally everything works: the script displays the expected string length. But once every several hours or even days, on the production server only (which hosts several heavily used applications), the bug "activates": the web server starts displaying special characters extracted from database wrong. Sometimes the bug "deactivates" by itself after some minutes; last time, it lasted several hours, then I run

```
service httpd restart
```

and the bug deactivated.

In the time frame when the bug is active, it is consistent: all requests to the web server for the page testfs1.php display the wrong result; however, when I manually run

```
php testfs1.php
```

on a command line of the server, the bug never appears, even when it is active.

This is the Bash script I leave running day and night to monitor the activation of the bug:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do
    echo -n `date +%H%M%S`
    wget https://www.mydomain.org/testfs1.php -o /dev/null
    echo -n "("
    cat testfs1.php
    echo -n ") "
    rm testfs1.php
    sleep 2
done
```

The PHP script I use to reproduce the issue:

```
<?php
$Conn = mssql_connect( 'PROD', 'user', 'password' ) ;
mssql_select_db( "DBPROD", $Conn ) ;
$Ret = mssql_query( "SELECT lname FROM people WHERE people_key=123", $Conn ) ;
list( $s ) = mssql_fetch_row( $Ret ) ;
print strlen( $s ) ;

?>
```

Here is locales.conf used by freeTDS:

```
[default]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = UTF-8

[en_US]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = UTF-8

[es_ES]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = UTF-8

[pt_BR]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = UTF-8

[it_IT]
    date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
    language = us_english
    charset = UTF-8
```

Summary of the most puzzling particularities of this issue:

1. Bug never happens when the script is run with PHP from the command line, only from Apache
2. Bug "activates" at different moments, once every several hours or few days, and either "deactivates" by itself or with a "service httpd restart"
3. When in the locales.conf used by freeTDS, the line [default]/charset was missing the bug was activating and deactivating spontaneously much more often (every few seconds)
4. When another application on the same server used gettext, the bug was activating and deactivating spontaneously much more often (every few seconds)

A colleague hints that it could be a memory problem, which makes some sense considering that restarting Apache could have freed memory, and explains why it does not happen on the test server, where the traffic is minimal. I am not convinced.

Can you imagine possible causes and solutions for the situation?

Comment: consider to use `mb_strlen( $s, 'UTF-8' );`

Comment: Check your other scripts to see if they set the connection to something other than UTF-8. If so, it might be that something isn't thread-safe or there is some connection pooling going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly i have no idea what makes such kind of inconsistent work. but i would like to advice you to change FreeTDS & unixODBC to stable releases. since FreeTDS lack of documentation & support. i am using v0.82 for along time. and it works fine.

https://gitorious.org/freetds/mars-freetds/source/52e59affc0110c5ddd379ef1e45c4554123f27b5:README#L2

Another way to look for problem detailed is using PDO MsSQL in testfs1.php. by this way you can address the problem better if native mssql extension has any effect on this inconsistency.

Comment: Is PDO mssql supported in latest PHP?
Does it go through freetds?